# Batch new line issue

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I have two files, `shell.bat` and `key.bat`. `shell.bat` calls `key.bat` and some other files in a directory called `etc`. `key.bat` asks for an ESSID from the user, finds the corresponding file in `etc` and `type`s its contents, which is the key for the ESSID requested. Afterward, `shell.bat` is called again, and the shell prompt, `server:wifi$` appears after the contents of the file `key.bat` called. Any ideas on how to fix this?

`shell.bat`: http://www.mediafire.com/view/skrs8e728023f6f/shell.bat

```
@echo off
set /p cmd=server:wifi$ 
if exist programs\%cmd%.bat goto cmd
goto fail

:cmd
call programs\%cmd%.bat
call shell.bat

:fail
echo Command "%cmd%" not found.
call shell.bat
```

`key.bat`:
http://www.mediafire.com/view/rm1v6czi3f4844c/key.bat

```
@echo off
set /p essid=ESSID: 
if exist etc\%essid%.txt goto key
goto fail

:fail
echo Key does not exist.
echo Add key with "mkkey".
goto :eof

:key
type etc\%essid%.txt
```

Comment: You need to post some code so we can see how it works. Don't just post links to the files.

Comment: @Smik Games, You say `shell.bat` is calling `key.bat`, but it appears `shell.bat` is calling `shell.bat` in the first example.

Comment: what are the %cmd%.bat files doing? Are they calling key.bat? Because key.bat is not being called from shell.bat.

Comment: "Fix" what? Your code repeatedly calls shell.bat which shows your `server:wifi$` - what do you WANT it to do? Eventually, it will run out of space and fail, but it will take a long time.  From what little you've shown us, if you respond to the server:wifi$ with `key` then it will prompt for `essid` and then either show the contents of that file or give instructions to add a new key. Er - what did you expect? What is it not doing that you expected it to do? What is it doing that you did not expect it to do? What did you want to do instead of the thing that it's doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modification and then tell us if there is still an issue, and describe further.

shell.bat

```
@echo off
set "cmd="
set /p cmd=server:wifi$ 
if exist "programs\%cmd%.bat" goto cmd
goto fail

:cmd
call "programs\%cmd%.bat"
%0

:fail
echo Command "%cmd%" not found.
%0
```

Key.bat

```
@echo off
set "essid="
set /p essid=ESSID: 
if exist "etc\%essid%.txt" goto key
goto fail

:fail
echo Key does not exist.
echo Add key with "mkkey".
goto :eof

:key
type "etc\%essid%.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding what I was asking. This fixed it perfectly.

Comment: Glad to help.  I added one further set of double quotes to support long filenames too.